# Need assistance making a simple game

Tags: python

I'm just wondering how I can make it so `elif player_position == 1` will work. I want to check the value of the argument (`pos`) in function `player_position()` and execute code depending on its value. I've only been learning Python for about 1 month.

```
def player_position(pos):

    position = pos

    if position == goliath.spawn:
        print('The Goliath Has Attacked!')

        if goliath.accuracy == 1:
            print('You Have Been Killed!')

        else:
            print('You Killed The Goliath!')

    else:
        print('Nothing Happens...')


def starting_room():

    while True:

        position_update = input('Enter A Direction: ')

        if position_update == 'Forwards':
            player_position(1)

        elif position_update == 'Backwards':
            player_position(3)

        elif position_update == 'Left':
            player_position(4)

        elif position_update == 'Right':
            player_position(2)

        elif player_position == 1:

            if position_update == 'Forwards':
                print('Room 2')

            elif position_update == 'Backwards':
                player_position(0)

            elif position_update == 'Left':
                print('There Are Monsters In the Dark')

            elif position_update == 'Right':
                print('There Are Monsters In The Dark')

starting_room()
```

Comment: `player_position` is a function which does not return anything.  You need to keep track of the position with a variable and update it each time you change direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a call to `player_position`, a function which does not return anything. Instead, assuming you want to keep track of the player's current position within your `starting_room` function, you'll want to keep track of the pos there.

Something like this: (note - you'll need to add more code to break out of the `while` loop - this code should allow you to keep track of the pos though)

```
def player_position(pos):
        position = pos
        if position == goliath.spawn:

            print('The Goliath Has Attacked!')

            if goliath.accuracy == 1:

                print('You Have Been Killed!')

            else:
                print('You Killed The Goliath!')

        else:
            print('Nothing Happens...')

def starting_room():
    pos = 0 #initialize the pos to 0
    while True:
        position_update = input('Enter A Direction: ')
        if pos == 1: #check to see if current pos is 1
            if position_update == 'Forwards':
                print('Room 2')
                #you may want to add "break" here to stop this while loop

            elif position_update == 'Backwards':
                pos = 0

            elif position_update == 'Left':
                print('There Are Monsters In the Dark')

            elif position_update == 'Right':
                print('There Are Monsters In The Dark')

        elif position_update == 'Forwards':
            pos = 1

        elif position_update == 'Backwards':
            pos = 3

        elif position_update == 'Left':
            pos = 4

        elif position_update == 'Right':
            pos = 2
        player_position(pos) #call the player_position function with the current pos

starting_room()
```